# Is there a way to pause current print job and start printing another document in windows 10?

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

Let's say I have a list of documents in the print queue. I am in urgent need of printing the last document.

The current print job will take 1 hour to finish. Is there a way to pause the current print job and print my document which is at the bottom of the queue and then resume printing the paused print job?

Edit 1:
I have tried pausing the current job and shifting the last job to the beginning of the queue. But unless the current job is either cancelled or completed, the queue does not resume on pausing. Thus I am stuck.

Comment: Perhaps select all but last jobs and right click and pause? I haven't used Windows in some time but i recall ability to pause single jobs so multiple jobs might work too. Maybe you can move it to the to of the queue...

Comment: Open Printers in the system tray. Look in the Up arrow if the icon is hidden.  See if the job is there and pause it. If the job is not there, then it has already spooled and gone.  Try turning off the printer and turning it back on.  Maybe just wait for the job to finish.

Comment: Perhaps cancel the current print job, print the other document, then resume printing the previous one from the page where it stopped.

Comment: @harrymc this is the only thing that works. But I don't want to cancel the current job. I want to *resume* the job on completion of the high priority temp job.

Comment: Did you try pausing it?  Also an hour has passed. It is finished?

Comment: @John As I was in a hurry, I cancelled the current job and printed the necessary document. But I want to know if its otherwise possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature of pausing a print job and switching to another really depends on your
printer driver. This is not a feature of Windows.

When the driver does not expose such an option, the only possibility is to cancel
the current print job, print the other document, then resume printing the previous
one from the page where it stopped. Cumbersome, but it works.

Comment: even cancelling it from from the print queue can be problematic.  Depending on the printer, the document might keep on printing after cancelling the job, as some or all of the print job is already in the printers memory.  You might have to cancel the job at the printer itself to get it to stop printing.